# How to update an object's property from another object ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

i have this state

```
interface ILeadsPageState {
  leadsList    : LeadBasicDto[]
  isLoading    : boolean;
  error        : any;
}
export interface ILeadsState {
  leadsListPage    : ILeadsPageState
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// State Initialization
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export const InitialLeadsState: ILeadsState = {
  leadsListPage    : {
    leadsList : [],
    isLoading : true,
    error     : null
  }
};
```

And my reducer is:

```
const leadsReducer = createReducer(
  InitialLeadsState,
  on(actions.loadLeads, (state) => **({ ...state, XXXXXXXXX  }))**, 
);
```

How I can modify the isLoading property on the action loadLeads, I don't find any way.

Comment: Yes you can, what have you tried? Usually you would have to set the value right after the spreaded state like: { ...state, isLoading: true/false }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on(actions.loadLeads, (state) => 
  ({  leadsListPage  : { ...state.leadsListPage,  isLoading: false }    })),
```

Or just use [ngrx-immer](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer#readme)

```
immerOn(actions.loadLeads, (state) => {
  state.leadsListPage.isLoading = false
}
```